# Sorted Doubly Linked List Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I got a problem here, implementing a Sorted Doubly Linked List of first and last names.

> Add a field to each link that indicates the alphabetically next first name; the existing next link is used to indicate the alphabetically next last name. You will also need a second root link for the list - the existing root link indicates the alphabetically first last name, and you will need one indicating the alphabetically first first name. Note that you will still only have one link object for each name entered in the list.
>
> Having done this, make any necessary changes to your insert, lookup, and delete methods so that both interleaved lists are maintained. Also update the runtime estimates as required to remain accurate.
>
> Finally, add a second lookup method that takes in a first name and returns all full names including that first name, and a second display method that prints the list of names out alphabetically by first name. Make sure you give runtime estimates for these methods as well.

And I am at a complete loss as how to do this. I already created a single linked list, with a first and last name, but that's as far as I was able to get.

Any Help would be great :D

Thank you.

Comment: Homework? If so, it should be tagged accordingly.

Comment: It seems like a home work Question. add homework tag if it is.

Comment: I don't think doubly linked list it the accurate term for your question. It sounds a lot more like a multiply linked list... since you want a link on two fields.A doubly linked list is use if you want to get the previous and the next firstname.

Comment: It was the closest thing I could think of as describing this data structure

Comment: That's ok, the only thing I want to know is if you want to be able to get the previous and the next item and sort OR you only want to sort your multiple linked list because in that case @sleeplessnerd have the right answer.

Comment: It's more a mutiply linked list, or 2 sorted linked lists together I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a Link Class that has two link fields (nextFirstName, nextLastName) and a field for the Name Object.
2. On insert, first search the Link object that comes before (LastName) this new one and insert it after that using the nextLastName field. Then do the same with the FirstName, using the nextFirstName field as the link.
3. ?????
4. profit!

This does smell a lot like homework :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have already implemented a Singly Linked List, expanding to a doubly linked list shouldn't be too difficult.  You already have references going forward (see picture below).  Now you need to add references going backward as well. In addition, note the blue lines in the picture below. Add additional references for the spelling properties. So each node will have the variables:

```
private Node NextFirstName;
private Node PreviousFirstName;
private Node NextLastName;
private Node PreviousLastName;
```

[image]

Comment: Right, I know about just adding backwards references, but how would I keep the data in both First name, and last name order?

Comment: You'll probably have to make a few passes whenever you insert to keep all the data in order.

Comment: The first thing I thought when I saw this was 'CRAP my 3 year old niece drew on the screen with a marker again!' :)

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT need backward-references! The task asks for something like 2 single-linked Lists, that use the same objects as entrys. Every object has two links: one to the next item in list A, and one to the next item in list B.